# Automounting riofs in ubuntu

Tags: mount, automount

I have several buckets mounted using the awesome [riofs](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) and they work great, however I'm at a loss trying to get them to mount after a reboot. I have tried entering in the following to my /etc/fstab with no luck:

`riofs#bucket-name /mnt/bucket-name fuse _netdev,allow_other,nonempty,config=/path/to/riofs.conf.xml 0 0`

I have also tried adding a startup script to run the riofs commands to my rc.local file but that too fails to mount them.

Any idea's or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Currently RioFS does not support fstab. In order to mount remote bucket at the startup time, consider adding corresponding command line to your startup script (rc.local, as you mentioned).

If for some reason it fails to start RioFS from startup script, please feel free to contact developers and/or fill issue report.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter your access key and secret access key in the riofs config xml file, then you should be able to mount this via fstab or an init.d or rc.local script ..

See [this thread](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs/issues/45)

#### `EDIT:`

I tested this myself and this is what I find.  Even with the AWS access details specified in the config file, there is no auto-matic mounting at boot.  But to access the system, all one needs to do is to issue `mount /mount/point/in-fstab` .. and the fstab directive would work and persist like a standard fstab mounted filesystem.

So, it seems the riofs system is not ready at that stage of the boot process when filesystems are mounted.  That's the only logical reason I can find so far.  This can be solved with an rc.local or init.d script that just issues a mount command (at the worst)

But riofs does work well, even as the documentation seems sparse.  It is certainly more reliable and less buggy than s3fs ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

I was able to get them auto-mounting from rc.local with the syntax similar to:

```
sudo riofs --uid=33 --gid=33 --fmode=0777 --dmode=0777 -o "allow_other" -c ~/.config/riofs/riofs.conf.xml Bucket-Name /mnt/mountpoint
```

Thanks again!